# Usart puzzle giving strange output on tx pins

Tags: pic, pcb, uart

I have tried working out  usart peripheral of pic18f26j50 and it found out to be working very well.

[image]

This one is for a pic18f26j50 in bread board with observing TX pin while transmitting in a loop.
This one showed maximum voltage of 3.44 v and mean of 2.10 as showed below.It showed constant frequency with a fluctuation of .6Khz from[2.5 khz to 3.1khz]

The next one is done on a pic18f47j53 Pcb board with two usarts and the transmit Tx pin is called in a loop.But i got terrible o/p and i'm posting the image here.

[image]

The o/p of the shows very distorting value when observed in a scope.
it showed maximum voltage in a changing range of 2.0-4.4 v and mean voltage in the range of -416mV-2.38V changing abruptly. 
The second one have an abrupt change in frequency from 2.6khz to 4khz and some times 9.6 khz too.

Do help me solve this problem if somebody experienced similar things before.

> The code is just setting the usart pins and configuring the baudrate
>   and transmitting in a while loop.

Comment: Looks to be oscillations as the actual data appears to be there still. Is the PCB setup with proper decoupling caps at the power input to the PIC?

Comment: Do you have the probes set to be DC coupled in that second capture? It looks to me like you might have it set for AC coupled.

Comment: No @PeterJ I have set the configuration correctly.And observed the waveforms one after another after setting the board connection and pcb connections.It's been a head ache ;) why the waveform is dancing like this

Comment: 100 points to all it was a power supply issue,:) Thanks a lot folks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn to use your scope properly.  These are clearly oscilloscope cockpit errors, not signal problems.  The first looks to be multiple traces superimposed, and the second is due to AC coupling instead of the desired DC coupling.

Comment: i was  powering my pub.board via a programmer and that was the cause of concern ..and doubt .I'll learn.sir .

Comment: @Rookie: That does not explain the AC-coupled nature of the traces in the bottom picture.